# c++ - should destructior be declared/implemented in pointerless class?

Tags: c++, implementation

Should destructior be declared/implemented in pointerless class?
Is there any advantage of having/not having it ?

What I men is:

```
class Point
{
public: 
    int X, Y;
    Point(int x, int y);
    //~Point(void);       //should I uncoment it and implement empty destructor ?
}
```

Comment: must read: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/dtors.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Should destructior be declared/implemented in pointerless class?**

No need<sup>[conditions apply]</sup>. the compiler will generate one for you.
You should provide one only if you want to perform something specific, which the compiler will not.
For example:

- Resource management(Memory managemnt, FIle handling),
- Logging,
- Close network connections,
- In short custom functionality which needs to execute each time a object is destroyed

In general the thumb rule is:
***"If you need to provide a copy constructor or a copy assignment operator then you most probably also need to provide your own destructor."***
Popularly, this rule is known as the **[Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)**.

---

<sup>[conditions apply]</sup>    If your class is meant to act as an Base class for Inheritance and your implementation will require calling `delete` on a Base class pointer pointing to a derived class object then you need to provide a destructor and mark it as `virtual` in Base class, failure to do so will result in **Undefined Behavior**.

---

> **Is there any advantage of having/not having it?**

None, since the compiler does the same there is no need to do the extra typing.

Comment: ... or if you want the destructor to be virtual.  But `Point` would not make a good base class.

Comment: @aschepler: You caught me in an edit.Added more detail to make it absolutely clear.Hth.

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't have a **non-`virtual`** destructor if you're not managing resources.

If you expect to derive from the class and plan on polymorphic deletion (i.e. `delete` a derived object through a base class pointer), you need a `virtual` destructor.

In fact, you shouldn't be managing resources directly, but have wrappers - i.e. smart pointers instead of raw pointers & manual allocation/deallocation.